# Best way to print list output in python

Tags: python, list

I have a `list` and a `list of list` like this

```
>>> list2 = [["1","2","3","4"],["5","6","7","8"],["9","10","11","12"]]
>>> list1 = ["a","b","c"]
```

I zipped the above two list so that i can match their value index by index.

```
>>> mylist = zip(list1,list2)
>>> mylist
[('a', ['1', '2', '3', '4']), ('b', ['5', '6', '7', '8']), ('c', ['9', '10', '11', '12'])]
```

Now I tried to print the output of above `mylist` using

```
>>> for item in mylist:
...     print item[0]
...     print "---".join(item[1])
...
```

It resulted in this output which is my `desired output`.

```
a
1---2---3---4
b
5---6---7---8
c
9---10---11---12
```

Now, my question is there a more `cleaner and better` way to achieve my desired output or this is the `best(short and more readable)` possible way.

Comment: not really, you can write `for name,lst in mylist: print name` instead of the indexing but i think thats all

Comment: One other comment -- if these two lists are really meant to be maintained side-by-side, you might want to consider storing them as a dictionary...

Comment: @mgilson: Thanks. I will definitely explore this option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you could avoid some temporary variables and use a nicer loop:

```
for label, vals in zip(list1, list2):
    print label
    print '---'.join(vals)
```

I don't think you're going to get anything fundamentally "better," though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just one more question is there any website like python doc or something where I can look for `best python practice`.

Comment: @Noob Here's the **PEP 8** Python Style guide in case you hadn't seen this before: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 4):

The following `for` loop will combine both the print and join operations into one line.

```
 for item in zip(list1,list2):
     print '{0}\n{1}'.format(item[0],'---'.join(item[1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

It may not be quite as readable as a full loop solution, but the following is still readable and shorter:

```
>>> zipped = zip(list1, list2) 
>>> print '\n'.join(label + '\n' + '---'.join(vals) for label, vals in zipped)
a
1---2---3---4
b
5---6---7---8
c
9---10---11---12
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to achieve the result.  It's shorter, but I'm not sure it's more readable:

```
print '\n'.join([x1 + '\n' + '---'.join(x2) for x1,x2 in zip(list1,list2)])
```

Answer (score 1):

What you might consider clean, but I do not, is that your the rest of your program needs to now the structure of your data and how to print it. IMHO that should be contained in the class of the data, so you can just do `print mylist` and get the desired result.

If you combine that with mgilson's suggestion to use a dictionary ( I would even suggest an OrderedDict) I would do something like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class MyList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        list.__init__(self, list(args))

    def __str__(self):
        return '---'.join(self)

class MyDict(OrderedDict):
    def __str__(self):
        ret_val = []
        for k, v in self.iteritems():
            ret_val.extend((k, str(v)))
        return '\n'.join(ret_val)

mydata = MyDict([
    ('a', MyList("1","2","3","4")),
    ('b', MyList("5","6","7","8")),
    ('c', MyList("9","10","11","12")),
])

print mydata
```

without requiring the rest of the program needing to know the details of printing this data.